# Is there any SAT Solver that provides a built-in library as Sat4j?

Tags: sat, sat-solvers, sat4j

As far as I know, Sat4j is a library that integrates SAT solver miniSAT on Java environment. I've searched on SAT competition (http://www.satcompetition.org/) and found that Kissat considered as the best SAT Solver so far.  Thus I wanna find a library that integrates Kissat (or Glucose is also ok) to test the performance.

1. Is there any SAT Solver that provides a build-in library as Sat4j?
2. If not, how to test Kissat and Glucose SAT Solver?
   Thanks a ton!

I've read source code of Kissat and Glucose SAT Solver but I dont understand how to test them by CNF file. Anyone used to work with it can help me?

Comment: Cryptominisat, Z3 or Google OR Tools are my recommendations. What programming language do you plan to use?

Comment: I'm using Java (Sat4j), so I want to find another library like Sat4j to implement, or else in other language is also ok.

Comment: @AxelKemper I've found in Sat competition 2022 that Kissat is now dominant. But I cannot find any document how to use them or at least how to put my CNF file based on DIMACS to run. Thus, I need your help. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Kissat](https://github.com/arminbiere/kissat) usage overview:

The commandline syntax of [Kissat](https://github.com/arminbiere/kissat):

```
usage: kissat [ <option> ... ] [ <dimacs> [ <proof> ] ]
```

To get extensive help

```
kissat --help
```

The `DIMACS CNF` file format is described [here](https://jix.github.io/varisat/manual/0.2.0/formats/dimacs.html).

You are supposed to download and build the [Kissat](https://github.com/arminbiere/kissat) executable. There are no precompiled binaries available in the official [Kissat](https://github.com/arminbiere/kissat) repository. The build process is working for *Unix* systems.

A volunteer provides [Kissat](https://github.com/arminbiere/kissat) *Windows* binaries and libraries on [GitHub](https://github.com/deiruch/kissat/releases/).

---

### Example:

```
kissat xxx.cnf.txt
```

Input file `xxx.cnf.txt`:

```
c CNF/DIMACS file for "<expression>"
c created: 27-Mar-2023 21:00:35
c by akBoole 06-Mar-2023
c command: akBoole "a and b" -d -o xxx.cnf.txt
c a 1
c b 2
c
p cnf 3 4
1 -3 0
2 -3 0
-1 -2 3 0
3 0
```

Resulting output:

```
c ---- [ banner ] ------------------------------------------------------------
c
c Kissat SAT Solver
c 
c Copyright (c) 2021-2022 Armin Biere University of Freiburg
c Copyright (c) 2019-2021 Armin Biere Johannes Kepler University Linz
c Ported to Windows, 2020 - 2022 Axel Kemper, Springe
c 
c Version sc2021-sweep unknown
c gcc.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0 -W -Wall -Wformat=0 -O3 -DNEMBEDDED -DNDEBUG -DNMETRICS -DNSTATISTICS -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -mno-ms-bitfields -I../src/pal-win -include global.h
c Sat, Jul 2, 2022 10:54:48 PM MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 akLand 3.3.5-341.x86_64 x86_64
c
c ---- [ parsing ] -----------------------------------------------------------
c
c opened and reading DIMACS file:
c
c   xxx.cnf.txt
c
c parsed 'p cnf 3 4' header
c closing input after reading 193 bytes
c finished parsing after 0.00 seconds
c
c ---- [ solving ] -----------------------------------------------------------
c
c  seconds switched rate      trail variables
c         MB reductions conflicts glue remaining
c          level restarts redundant irredundant
c
c *  0.02  0 0 0 0  0 0   0   0 0% 0  3  0 0%
c {  0.02  0 0 0 0  0 0   0   0 0% 0  3  0 0%
c }  0.02  0 0 0 0  0 0   0   0 0% 0  3  0 0%
c 1  0.02  0 0 0 0  0 0   0   0 0% 0  3  0 0%
c
c ---- [ result ] ------------------------------------------------------------
c
s SATISFIABLE
v 1 2 3 0
c
c ---- [ profiling ] ---------------------------------------------------------
c
c           0.00    0.00 %  search
c           0.00    0.00 %  simplify
c =============================================
c           0.02  100.00 %  total
c
c ---- [ statistics ] --------------------------------------------------------
c
c conflicts:                                0                0.00 per second
c decisions:                                0                0.00 per conflict
c propagations:                             3              192    per second
c
c ---- [ resources ] ---------------------------------------------------------
c
c maximum-resident-set-size:          3166208 bytes          3 MB
c process-time:                                              0.02 seconds
c
c ---- [ shutting down ] -----------------------------------------------------
c
c exit 10
```

Note two special and significant output lines:

```
s SATISFIABLE
v 1 2 3 0
```

The example has a solution, i.e. is *satisfiable*. The three input variables all have the value `1/true`.